# Associations in Sequelize migrations

Tags: node.js, associations, database-migration, sequelize.js

My app currently uses the Sequelize `sync()` method to create the database, and I want to change it to use the migrations system.

One of my model has `belongsTo()` associations with other models, and I don't really know how to make the initial migration code for these associations.

Do I have to manually create the foreign key with SQL queries, or is there some methods available?

Comment: You want to use migrations to create initial database structure or you want to update your current database structure using migrations?

Comment: I want to create the initial database structure first

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Case 1: Database initialization**

If your purpose is to add relations during initialization of database structure it is better to just use `sync` method instead of manually adding them using migrations. If your models are properly designed and have relations defined, they will be created automatically during execution of `sync` method.

Take a look at [sequelize express example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example). In models directory you have three files:

- `index.js` - which includes all models
- `task.js` - task model
- `user.js` - user model

Look at `task.js` content, starting from line 7 the following code creates a relation between User and Task models:

```
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
    Task.belongsTo(models.User, {
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If you correctly prepare your relations in model files, sync will create the foreign keys for you. Migrations aren't necessary in this case.

I encourage you to read the whole express-example `readme.md` and browse repository files to see how the things work with express and sequelize.

**Case 2: Database structure migration**

In case you already have some data which you want to keep, you need to use migration script, because the only way for sync to restructure your database is to destroy it completely alongside with all its data.

You can read about basic [migrations in the sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/). Unfortunately docs do not cover creating a relation. Let's assume you want to create the following relation: User belongs to Group. To create column on the user side of relation, you may use `addColumn` method.

```
queryInterface.addColumn(
  'user',
  'group_id',
  {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: true
  }
)
```

Unfortunately there isn't a nice function (yet) to create the foreign key constraint for you, but you can do it manually using sequelize query method. Postgresql example:

```
queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TABLE user
  ADD CONSTRAINT user_group_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
  REFERENCES group (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;");
```

Edit: Added database structure migration case

Comment: Hmm ok thanks. I think i'm a bit confused about the differences between the migrations and the sync and when to use them. So if I updated my models using only sync() will it migrate my database correctly?

Comment: Sync creates a clean database structure based on your current models. If force attribute is set to false it will only create database if it does not already exist. Otherwise it will wipe the whole database each time you restart the server. Migrations scripts are used to change your existing database by operating on already existing structure and data. It is useful in production environment where you want to keep your data between updates.

Comment: Down voting because question is specifically about migrations (which you need for production) and this answer does not answer that.  (But good answer for `sync`).

Comment: @AJP Thanks for your comment. I updated my answer to contain both cases: initial creation using sync and database migration.

Comment: @ezrepotein yeah that's what I've doing for the moment.  Thanks for updating your answer.  Pretty nasty we have to do it this way, the functionality is in there but I'm not quite sure how to pull it out yet.  Will post back if I find a nicer solution.

Comment: @ezpn for some reason, it won't add the on UPDATE and DELETE properties to the foreign key constraint. Any ideas?

Comment: As of May '17, you can create the foreign key constraint within the migration. See here: https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/239#issuecomment-166564364

Answer (score 13):

Adding this as an answer instead of a comment (not enough rep) for @aryeh-armon answer above. It's the table name that you need to make sure exists rather than the model name. i.e. if your model is named Job and your db table is named Jobs then the migration would look look like this instead.

```
jobId: {
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
references: {
    model: "Jobs",
    key: "id"
  }
},
```

Comment: It's a clarification on aryeh armon's answer (which, I agree, should be a comment) but I don't have enough rep to comment on other user's answers yet.

Answer (score 3):

you can add references to the migrations

Exmaple:

```
user_id: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    references: {
        model: "users",
        key: "id"
    }
},
```

Just make sure the model you are referencing exists.

Answer (score 2):

After lots of searching, I found a couple of blog posts explaining what I wanted to do. The first one no longer exists, and [here's the second one](https://bulkan-evcimen.com/using-sequelize-migrations-with-an-existing-database)

Apparently it's not really the common way to do it, but it seems more logical to me. If you want to use only the migrations, you have to use SQL queries to create the initial migration.

But anyway, I think that ezpn is right about creating the initial database with sync, and then migrate. It seems easier than using umzug and only use migrations.

Comment: I agree with everything up until last sentence.  You need migrations for production code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the possible use case for using migrations to initialize database on production?

Comment: @ezrepotein  sync is fine for db creation obviously just the question title is phrased in the more general (and therefore useful) "Associations in Sequelize migrations".  I actually prefer using migrations on production though, why not if you do it for your test db too.  Then your db setup and update use the same declarative command such as `sequelize db:migrate`, instead of some `if no db, then db:sync, otherwise db:migrate` kinda thing.  I think there's a generally accepted minor preference for the former over the later.

Comment: @ezpn If you use sync() to create your structure, you run into an issue if you ever alter tables via migrations. Example: You create a migration to add column X to table Y. It works...great. A month later a new developer joins the team and runs npm start. He gets an error saying "Failed to run migration....column X already exists on table Y". Why is this? Because your sync command took care of the column addition, and now the migration is not needed. Sync() wasn't designed to actually be used. This poor implementation is one of the negatives of using sequelize.

Comment: Those links you described now turns into spam with redirects to random pages !.

Comment: @user8969730 thanks! I think the first one is lost, but the second one appears to have a slightly different URL. It's been a long time since I worked on this project, so I could not describe what I did back then, the best I can do is update the link, sorry. And this is maybe outdated, check the comments on the other answers.